# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException even after encoding a String in android app

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

in my app i am trying to send an email and password to an url and in return i use to get either success message or error message. When i hit the api the return data came as follows

```
10-07 18:09:41.209: ERROR Data ?Error: Email and password do not match. Please try again!
10-07 18:10:47.698: ERROR Error(6363): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

the problem is because of the `?` before the word Error

So i thought of encoding the return data in my code as follows

```
HttpResponse rsp = client.execute(get);
tmpstr = URLEncoder.encode(EntityUtils.toString(rsp.getEntity()),"utf-8"); 
Log.e("Data ",""+tmpstr);
```

i tried out in the above and below method

```
HttpResponse rsp = client.execute(get);
tmpstr = URLEncoder.encode(EntityUtils.toString(rsp.getEntity()),"utf-8"); 
Log.e("Data ",""+tmpstr);
String data = URLEncoder.encode(tmpstr,"UTF-8");
Log.e("returned dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa ",""+data);
```

In the both the codes i am getting the same error as follows

```
10-07 21:01:47.698: ERROR(6363): Data %EF%BB%BFError%3A+Email+and+password+do+not+match.+Please+try+again%21
10-07 21:01:47.698: ERROR(6363): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

how to solve this issue

Comment: Are you sure this is not the error message that indicates that the pass is incorrect for the email that was entered?

Comment: Can you show the traceback for the exception? Can you locate/show the code that throws the exception?

Comment: @Tim my error response from the URL is supposed to be this "Error: Email and password do not match. Please try again!" , but i what i am getting is this "?Error: Email and password do not match. Please try again!"

Comment: Please post some more of your logcat - stacktrace woes not show what really happenging ( and where)

Comment: i am just getting the following two lines only    ERROR Data ?Error: Email and password do not match. Please try again!
10-07 18:10:47.698: ERROR Error(6363): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @Konstantin Pribluda - i get a return data which i am printing in the ddms and it is followed by the the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and all operations gets stopped in my app

Comment: After `Log.e("Data",""+tmpstr);`, add `return;` or `return null;` just stop everything. Tell us if you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` again

Comment: i tried by typing "return null;" Now the return data gets printed and it moved to the next function, but i need the return data for my further proceeding, for my next if else conditions. what can i do for it....

Comment: I'm sure you can get more info from LogCat, open that window and get from there stack trace. It will be more helpful to find an issue. Post stack trace with error (in red) here if it doesn't say you anything helpful. From what I see nothing in your code should throw "ArrayIndexOut..." exception

Comment: @Maxim - what you said is rite. I am using the return data for my further use and in that place only i am gettin the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. PLs post your comment on the answers part and i will accept your answer, thanx

Comment: Thanks Siva K, glad those comment helped you. I posted my comment but @Robert Harvey deleted it, because it's not considered as an answer. Robert, as a moderator you should read posts more careful and at least ask to change comment to answer style post like SLaks did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this question is given by [Maxim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323128/maxim) in the comments part. i have mentioned this here in order to close this question....

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have to use `URLEncoder` to encode such error messages? I guess the `URLEncoder` expect some string formatted like URL, and the string that you pass doesn't looks like an url.

Comment: i dint have any choice so i am using that URLEncoder. Is there any other way pls suggest me.....

Comment: what do you mean that you have no any choice?

Comment: anyway, the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown by the URLEncoder.encode(tmpstr,"UTF-8"); , which means that this is not correct string format for this function. A workaround should be to catch the exception and deal with the tempstr in the catch section.